# How do I run two docker containers in the same backend that can accept connections on multiple ports?

Tags: traefik

I need to run two identical containers behind Traefik which have to accept requests coming in on multiple ports. To do this I am using [docker service labels](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/#on-service). The problem that I am running into is when I use Docker service labels and try to scale up to two containers I get an error message about the backend already being defined.

Using the normal labels (`traefik.frontend`, `traefik.port` etc.) works fine, but adding the extra labels (`traefik.whoami.frontend`, `traefik.whoami.port` etc.) seems to break things.

Docker compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  whoami:
    image: emilevauge/whoami
    networks:
      - web
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.docker.localhost"
      - "traefik.http.port=80"
      - "traefik.http.frontend.entryPoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.frontend.backend=whoami"

      - "traefik.soap.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.docker.localhost"
      - "traefik.soap.port=8443"
      - "traefik.soap.frontend.entryPoints=soap"
      - "traefik.soap.frontend.backend=whoami"

networks:
  web:
    external:
      name: traefik_webgateway
```

Scale up:

```
$ docker-compose scale whoami=2
Creating and starting whoami_whoami_2 ... done
```

Traefik error log:

```
proxy_1  | time="2017-10-23T15:37:16Z" level=error msg="Near line 39 (last key parsed 'backends.backend-whoami.servers'): Key 'backends.backend-whoami.servers.service' has already been defined."
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here or if there is another way to map two ports to a container?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug with Docker replicas management.

A fix will be merged in the next release : https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/2314.